# Seurat installation fails

Tags: r, seurat

When I am trying to install `Seurat` in `R markdown file`:

```
install.packages("Seurat")
```

it fails with the following errors:

```
Installing package into ‘/sfs/qumulo/qhome/nv4e/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘proxy’ is not available
also installing the dependencies ‘igraph’, ‘dtw’, ‘diffusionMap’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/igraph_1.2.1.tar.gz'

Content type 'unknown' length 2703426 bytes (2.6 MB)

downloaded 2.6 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/dtw_1.18-1.tar.gz'

Content type 'unknown' length 849256 bytes (829 KB) downloaded 829 KB trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/diffusionMap_1.1-0.tar.gz'

Content type 'unknown' length 39130 bytes (38 KB)
downloaded 38 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Seurat_2.3.0.tar.gz'

Content type 'unknown' length 846065 bytes (826 KB)

downloaded 826 KB
* installing *source* package ‘igraph’ ...
** package ‘igraph’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
installing to /sfs/qumulo/qhome/nv4e/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/igraph/libs
** R
** demo
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded

Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :    unable to load shared object '/sfs/qumulo/qhome/nv4e/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/igraph/libs/igraph.so': libicui18n.so.58: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Error: loading failed Execution halted ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/sfs/qumulo/qhome/nv4e/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/igraph’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘igraph’ had non-zero exit status

ERROR: dependency ‘proxy’ is not available for package ‘dtw’
* removing ‘/sfs/qumulo/qhome/nv4e/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/dtw’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘dtw’ had non-zero exit status

ERROR: dependency ‘igraph’ is not available for package ‘diffusionMap’
* removing ‘/sfs/qumulo/qhome/nv4e/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/diffusionMap’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘diffusionMap’ had non-zero exit status

ERROR: dependencies ‘igraph’, ‘dtw’, ‘diffusionMap’ are not available for package ‘Seurat’
* removing ‘/sfs/qumulo/qhome/nv4e/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Seurat’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘Seurat’ had non-zero exit status
```

How could it be fixed? What to try?

Operating system is `CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)`

> Update

I also tried development version of `Seurat` but it failed too:
http://satijalab.org/seurat/devinstall.html

> Update

I tried installing `Seurat` using `conda install -c bioconda r-seurat` and it is not working. It is giving the error:

> -bash-4.2$ conda install -c bioconda r-seurat 
>   Fetching package metadata .............
>   Solving package specifications:
>
> PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

- r-seurat -> r-cowplot
- r-seurat -> r-diffusionmap
- r-seurat -> r-dtw
- r-seurat -> r-ggridges
- r-seurat -> r-ica
- r-seurat -> r-pbapply
- r-seurat -> r-ranger
- r-seurat -> r-rcppprogress
- r-seurat -> r-sdmtools
- r-seurat -> r-tclust

> We have searched for the packages in the following channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/linux-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch

Comment: You seem to be missing the `libicui18n.so` library. Please [edit] your question and tell us what operating system you are using. If Linux, tell us what distribution.

Comment: I just updated. It is `CentOS`. I am working with `rstudio` on the cluster.

Comment: Ah, thanks. So what is the output of `yum search libicui18n` (if that returns nothing, try `yum search libicui` or even `yum search icui` until you get a result). Then, install the package. If that works, let me know and I can post answer (or just post it yourself, up to you).

Comment: The output in all the three cases is `No matches found`. Also, I do not have `root` privileges obviously, so maybe I should download this `libicui18n.so` library and install it locally somehow?

Comment: Hmm, I haven't used an rpm-based system in ages. You might need to search for `libicui*` or something. I did check CentOS's repository, and there is such a package. I don't remember how to install rpms locally though and I'm on mobile, so I can't help much. You could try asking how to find and install the relevant package on [unix.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @terdon mentioned in the comments, you need to `sudo yum install libicu` on the relevant nodes (or have your admin do that for you). Alternatively, seurat can be installed via conda, which means you don't need root access.

Comment: Actually I tried installing `Seurat` using `conda install -c bioconda r-seurat ` and it is not working. It is giving `PackageNotFoundError`.

Comment: You need `-c conda-forge` too. You might then need to fix readline with `conda upgrade -c conda-forge readline`.

Comment: If you don't wish to use conda as your r package manager (because, for a start, it will install a new copy of R with its own library), you can install just ICU with conda `conda install -c conda-forge icu`, and then install seurat in R